# Search li for duplicates using jquery, if found remove both

Tags: jquery, filter, html-lists

I know it's possible to use Jquery to search for a duplicated `<li>` tag and remove it, but what I accually want to do is when a duplicate is found, remove both instances of the li.

Example:

```
<li>foo
<li>bar
<li>foo
<li>test
<li>me
<li>bar
```

the Jquery should return the output

```
<li>test
<li>me
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First that came to my mind:

```
$("li").filter(function() {
    var text = this.innerHTML,
        el = $(this).siblings("li").filter(function() {
            return this.innerHTML == text;
        }).remove();
    return el.length > 0;
}).remove();​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/x5QQZ/